# The ggpredict function returns incomplete confidence intervals for a linear mixed midel with an interaction

Tags: confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot showing the LMM prediction with confidence intervals using the `ggpredict` function from the `ggeffect` package. The model consists of three fixed effects, one of which is an interaction.

```
MODEL.I <- lmer(
  NLR_CHANGE
  ~ (1|ID)
  + AGE
  + HYPOTHYROIDISM:NLR1
  + NLR1
  ,
  REML = TRUE,
  data = DATA6
)
```

The ggpredict function does not produce complete confidence intervals. With the following code:

```
ggpredict(MODEL.I, terms = c("NLR1", "HYPOTHYROIDISM", 
          "AGE[25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65]"))
```

I get the following output:

```
# HYPOTHYROIDISM = FALSE
#          AGE = 25

   x | Predicted |         95% CI
---------------------------------
0.00 |      0.61 | [ 0.31,  0.91]
1.50 |     -0.38 | [-0.66, -0.09]
2.50 |     -1.03 | [-1.51, -0.55]
5.00 |     -2.67 |               

# HYPOTHYROIDISM = TRUE
#          AGE = 25

   x | Predicted |        95% CI
--------------------------------
0.00 |      0.61 | [ 0.35, 0.87]
1.50 |      0.09 | [-0.23, 0.42]
2.50 |     -0.25 |              
5.00 |     -1.11 |              

# HYPOTHYROIDISM = FALSE
#          AGE = 30

   x | Predicted |         95% CI
---------------------------------
0.00 |      0.67 | [ 0.40,  0.95]
1.50 |     -0.31 | [-0.56, -0.06]
2.50 |     -0.97 | [-1.43, -0.51]
5.00 |     -2.61 |               

# HYPOTHYROIDISM = TRUE
#          AGE = 30

   x | Predicted |        95% CI
--------------------------------
0.00 |      0.67 | [ 0.44, 0.90]
1.50 |      0.16 | [-0.14, 0.46]
2.50 |     -0.18 |              
5.00 |     -1.04 |
```

and so on...

Using this output I get the following incomplete graph.

[image]

What can I do to get the confidence intervals for the full range of variable values?